# Consulta JAVA com ACCESS - Lentidão

Tags: java, netbeans, microsoft-access

estou precisando acessar o banco de dados ACCESS, a consulta está acessando corretamente, porém reparei que para ter o retorno das informações, o JAVA primeiro faz a leitura e todas as tabelas e todas os dados, é isso mesmo? não tem uma forma dele realizar a consulta somente aquilo que é solicitado?

Classe DAO:

// Nome do arquivo

```
    String filename = "\\\\arquivo.mdb";
    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + filename.trim();
    // Realiza a conexão com o banco de dados
    String usuario = "";
    String senha = "";
    conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
    return conexao;
```

a Consulta:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ATENDIMENTO");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("DATA"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("CLIENTE"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O UCanAccess usa um "banco de dados espelho" HSQLDB que por padrão é armazenado na memória e deve ser recriado quando o seu aplicativo abre o banco Access. Isso envolve copiar os dados das tabelas do Access para as tabelas HSQLDB, o que pode levar algum tempo se o banco Access for grande. Ter o banco Access em uma área de rede compartilhada irá tornar o processo ainda mais lento.

Se houver pouca chance do banco Access ser alterado com muita frequência entre as vezes que você abre seu aplicativo Java então você pode usar o parâmetro de conexão keepMirror do UCanAccess para persistir o banco espelho em uma pasta no seu disco local. Isso reduziria o tempo de inicialização do seu aplicativo porque UCanAccess não teria que reconstruir o banco espelho a cada vez. Veja o [site do UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) para maiores detalhes.

Outra possibilidade de lentidão é quando o banco está armazenado em uma subpasta profunda de um drive/servidor compartilhado (no caso da [pergunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118315/2241463) ele estava armazenado na sexta subpasta a partir da raiz). No momento do primeiro acesso, o mecanismo de segurança do servidor faz uma checagem a cada pasta que ele adentra. Movendo a pasta para a raiz, a conexão fica mais rápida.

---

Dicas gerais:

- Se você só precisa dos campos `DATA` e `CLIENTE`, especifique-os no `SELECT` em vez de usar `*`:

  SELECT DATA, CLIENTE FROM ATENDIMENTO
- Se você só precisa de registros específicos (por exemplo posteriores a uma certa data), acrescente isso no `WHERE`:

  SELECT DATA, CLIENTE FROM ATENDIMENTO WHERE DATA >= (...)
- Se mesmo assim a quantidade de dados retornada for muito grande, procure paginá-la:

  SELECT DATA, CLIENTE FROM ATENDIMENTO WHERE (...) LIMIT 1, 20

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, eu sempre faço isso, contudo como estou apenas testando, dei um select *. O problema que observei é que ele esta lendo o banco de dados inteiro para depois carregar as informações, e é isso que eu estou questionando, isso está certo mesmo?

Comment: Entendi, é uma lentidão que ocorre antes mesmo de se fazer o select. [Essa resposta em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32011512/2241463) explica o motivo e dá uma forma de resolver. Vou traduzi-la em breve.

Comment: Tradução feita.